# In the flink program, how to customize the multi-parallel Source to read the HBase partition table

Tags: apache-flink

In the flink program, how to customize the multi-parallel Source to read the HBase partition table.

```
For example, there are 9 partitions, 3 degrees of parallelism, and one degree of parallelism reads the data of 3 partitions, and it is guaranteed to be accurate once
```

```
How to realize the correspondence between parallelism and partition after implementing ParallelSourceFunction
```

How to ensure the accuracy of the data here